# why positioned div is not expanding?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `position:absolute, left:0, right:0; widht:100%`. This is fine with my code.
But when i have added another div, which it has `width:2000px;` my first div width is not expanding. Can you please suggest me.

This is my example. http://jsfiddle.net/vYhv4/

Thanks

Comment: what does the css look like?   it's hard to give assistance if we don't know what you have currently.  If you don't have overflow: specified in the css try setting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `position:absolute` property positions the element relative to its ancestor element, in your case that is the `body` of the document, which is not the width of your `.displayElement` class. One thing you can do to fix this is to contain both your `.displayElement` class and your absolutely positioned div, `.box`, inside of a container that is clearfixed that acts as the ancestor of your `.box` div, positioned relative.

Like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="element-container">
    <div class="box">test</div>
    <div class="displayElement">
        flash slider comes here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.element-container:before, .element-container:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.element-container:after {
    clear:both;
}

.element-container {
    zoom:1; /* ie  hasLayout fix */
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/vYhv4/3/)

Comment: Your solutions is excellent. but one more doubt ... when i applied to width:500px;overflow:auto; to element-container, why again the box div is not expanding in this case?

Comment: @PavanKumar You have to remember that the `element-container` div is only acting as a container div that is positioned relative so your `box` div can expand the width of your `displayElement` div, so where you really should be adding the width is on that element, `displayElement`. If you do set a width on the container div, that is the width that the `box` div will pick up.

Comment: so, in that case cant we do anything?

Comment: @PavanKumar Anything as in what? What is your desired result? If you add `width:500px` to the `element-container` div, and your `displayElement` div extends past that because its width is set to `2000px`, are you still expecting your `box` div to expand to the width of your `displayElement` div regardless of what width you give its container? What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @PavanKumar Added a background color to the `element-container` rule to illustrate how it is covering your divs: http://jsfiddle.net/vYhv4/7/ .. try to lower the width of your `displayElement` div so you can see why it is being used.

Comment: yes i understand andres. Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/HqSZS/ what i want the result. Actually i have to show one table in 500px width area. When i am scrolling horizontal the header background color is missing.

Comment: @PavanKumar can you explain what is the issue on the link?

Comment: what you said before comments you are right, it pickups the width of the container. I am trying to cover the problem, but need to show full table....

Comment: @PavanKumar You're asking 2 different questions here so open up a new thread with your new question, but here is a fixed version showing you how my answer above applies to the same case: http://jsfiddle.net/HqSZS/1/

Comment: You are awesome. Working perfect. Thanks Alot. Actually i confused how to show/ask. sorry for inconvinence.

Comment: A user will not know there is more data present below until he scrolls completely towards right side and sees the vertical scroll bar. How can I be able to show the vertical scrollbar withought the need to move the horizontal scrollbar completly towards right side.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am asking for: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: @Shivanand that can be accomplished with a mask and his `verticalScroll` div is already acting like one, all OP has to do is remove the `overflow` declaration from it, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HqSZS/2/

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is to keep the header fixed when I scroll down.

Comment: @Shivanand `position:absolute` is not the best solution for a fixed header inside a table, that is what `position:fixed` is for, in the case of the table that the OP posted, it works because the container for the table is being given an overflow attribute that allows the table only to scroll, and not the table headers (since they are positioned absolutely) along with the bg div. This method won't work with fixed table headers, but will work with the initial question. So, do a look up for another method, [there are plenty in this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fixed+table+headers).

Comment: This one is the perfect solution I guess: http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/jQuery_FixedTable_Demo.htm

Comment: Hi Andres, May i know why did you use these classes - element-container:before, .element-container:after{}

Comment: @PavanKumar its called a clearfix and its meant to contain elements within their boundaries while clearing other elements around it (in other words making a box act like a box). You can find more info here, which is the clearfix i used: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

The first div will only expand to the width of the viewable area, it will not expand past that until you specify a width that is greater.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because .box is aligning itself to the body. However, the body is 100% wide and isn't growing when .displayElement becomes wider than the viewport.

Is there any reason why you can't set the .box width to 2000px as well?

Comment: That .box purpose is differnt for my requirement. So i cant give 2000px. Actually i wont give the 2000px. it takes with my picture. Some pictures may have 200px to 3000px also.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your parent container has a width set that is smaller than your 2000px element. I think as you have your div absolutely positioned with left and right being 0 your width will be the width of your parent container. width:100% wont expand your container to the width of child containers but to the parent.